# Php Mailer error - Godaddy Smtp

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a project in which I have to send 100-200 mails to users but every mail has different token for each user. I have the email hosted on godaddy.

So I was looking to send email using phpmailer. Below is the script which I am testing but it keeps giving me this error -

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

```
<?php

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'mailm/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug   = 2;
$mail->DKIM_domain = '127.0.0.1';
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host        = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port        = 465;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth    = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username    = "itsupport@mysite.ae";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password    = "Mypassword";
$mail->SMTPSecure  = 'ssl';
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('itsupport@mysite.ae', 'IT Helpdesk');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('sgajara@gmail.com', 'IT Helpdesk');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->Body = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file


//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

This script I have found on a blog.

Any alternatives to this are also welcomed, My purpose is to send 200 emails from my godaddy email account but every email has a separate token which is fetched from the database and then inserted in the mail body and sent to the user.

Comment: but it sounds to me the issue is not related to the specific code, but it's related to the "SMTP authorization". how you made sure SMTP connection is established and mail server is set-up properly?

Comment: Aside from the GoDaddy auth issue, base your code on [the mailing list example provided wth PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Answer (score 0):

That is so simple:

You must focus on smtp host, port, ssl...
Change smtp host to: relay-hosting.secureserver.net
And DELETE port and ssl, thats all...
Do not use smtp port and smtp ssl true or false...

```
    var fromAddress = "mailfrom@yourdomain";
    // any address where the email will be sending
    var toAddress = "mailto@yourdomain";
    //Password of your mail address
    const string fromPassword = "******";
    // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
    string subject = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    string body = "From: " + TextBox2.Text + "\n";
    body += "Email: " + TextBox3.Text + "\n";
    body += "Subject: " + TextBox4.Text + "\n";
    body += "Message: \n" + TextBox5.Text + "\n";
    // smtp settings
    var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    {
        smtp.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
**//Warning Delete =>//smtp.Port = 80;**
**//Warning Delete =>//smtp.EnableSsl = false;**
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtp.Timeout = 20000;
    }
    // Passing values to smtp object
    smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify few configurations mentioned below. let me know if this works or not.

```
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = 25;  
$mail->ssl = false;
$mail->authentication = false;
```